# Finding Duplicates in Java

Tags: java, array

I am trying to figure out a way to make finding duplicates in Java more efficient. I started off with this:

```
private boolean hasDuplicates(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
    for(int num : array) {
        list.add(num);
    }
    for(int num : list) {
        if(list.indexOf(num) != list.lastIndexOf(num)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the main problem here is it only can be used if you were to find duplicate numbers. So I made it generic:

```
private <E> boolean hasDuplicates(E[] array) {
    List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>(array.length);
    for(E e : array) {
        list.add(e);
    }
    for(E e : list) {
        if(list.indexOf(e) != list.lastIndexOf(e)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is what I currently have, but it seems very inefficient, so I tried this:

```
private static <E> boolean hasDuplicates(E[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    int length = array.length - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(array[i].equals(array[i + 1])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But that would throw a `ClassCastException` if it cannot be cast to `java.lang.Comparable` during `Arrays.sort()`. Which returns to the old, inefficient method.

Is there a better solution than this? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a Set.

```
private <E> boolean hasDuplicates(E[] array) {
    Set<E> set = new HashSet<E>();
    for(E e : array) {
        if (!set.add(e)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

The [`add()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) of a set returns false if the object already exists in the set.

Comment: Simplicity at it's very best, really. Can't get any easier than this.

Comment: I just realized that if `E` does not override `hashCode()` and `equals()`, the code will not work well.

Comment: @MannyMeng you need those for your implementation anyway. This code is an improvement on those methods, with the same assumptions.